# Future<List<Notes>> to Stream so i can use it in stream builder

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
static String _url = "https://notes-7f146-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com";

static Future browse() async {
    final List<Notes> _notes = [];
    var respose = await http.get(Uri.parse(_url + '/notes.json?'));

    final extractedData =
        await convert.json.decode(respose.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    extractedData.forEach((key, value) {
      _notes.add(Notes(
          title: value['title'], desc: value['desc'], key: key.toString()));
    });
    // _notes = collection.map((json) => Notes.fromJson(json)).toList();
    return _notes;
}
```

How can I make a stream from this?

Answer (score 0):

You can transform a Future into a Stream by using `Stream.fromFuture(dur)`.

If you declutter your question into something readeable I will be able to use that in this answer. ;)